# Bootstrap- layout of Two column with one column having two row and one with three layout using only one parent container

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid, responsive

I am trying to create layout of two column inside one parent div with html structure like this [layout-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqT7x.png)

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="item large column-1 row-1"></div>
 <div class="item column-1 row-2"></div>
 <div class="item column-1 row-2"></div>
 <div class="item column-2 row-1"></div>
 <div class="item column-2 row-2"></div>
 <div class="item column-2 row-1"></div>
</div>
```

So far I have managed something like this with using bootstrap grid.
https://codepen.io/1pavan/pen/OJypmxR

I know it can be achieved using 2 wrapper div inside container like:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item large column-1 row-1"></div>
    <div class="item column-1 row-2"></div>
    <div class="item column-1 row-2"></div>
</div>
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item column-2 row-1"></div>
   <div class="item column-2 row-2"></div>
   <div class="item column-2 row-1"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

But i want to achieve it using the first one div structure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need structure like that?

Comment: I dont want to use extra divs.